# Check Entity Size in Google cloud

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, ndb

I am trying to find the entity size in google cloud. However entity._to_pb() is throwing an attribute error. Can anyone help to find entity size from google cloud ndb.

```
    from google.cloud import ndb

    _MAX_ENTITY_SIZE_DATASTORE = 1048572

    def CheckEntitySizeTooBig(entity):
        max_size = _MAX_ENTITY_SIZE_DATASTORE
        if len(entity._to_pb().Encode()) > max_size:
            return False
        return True
```

AttributeError: 'ImageryRequest' object has no attribute '_to_pb'.

Is there any new way to find entity size which i am missing out. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code worked for me

```
from google.cloud.ndb.model import _entity_to_protobuf

_MAX_ENTITY_SIZE_DATASTORE = 1048572

def CheckEntitySizeTooBig(entity):
    max_size = _MAX_ENTITY_SIZE_DATASTORE
    entity_to_proto = _entity_to_protobuf(entity)
    if len(entity_to_proto().SerializeToString()) > max_size:
        return True
    return False
```